# Iterate through html table and calculates value

Tags: javascript, dom, data-binding, event-handling, dom-events

The goal is that people should enter a value in the input field and JavaScript should multiply with a fixed value.

The code should do this for every row and do this automatically without refreshing.

JavaScript works for the first row but if I add the loop (first 3 lines of code) then it doesn't work anymore.

The Table looks like this

```
<table class="u-table-entity" id="table_gebäck">
  <script src="calculation.js"></script>
  <colgroup>
    <col width="20%">
    <col width="2.1%">
    <col width="22%">
    <col width="21.7%">
    <col width="34.2%">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody class="u-table-alt-grey-5 u-table-body">
    <tr style="height: 55px;">
      <b>
      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-1"><b>Produkt</b><span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-3"><b>Einzelpreis</b></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-4"><b>Menge</b></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-5"><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
      </b>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 55px;">
      <td class="u-table-cell">Kornspitz</td>
      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <p value="1.39" id="basePrice">1,39 €</p>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <form id="Menge">
          <input type="number" min="0" id="quantity" value="0" step="1.0">
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <form id="sum">
          <p><output id="field_sum" for="quantity">0</output> €</p>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 55px;">
      <td class="u-table-cell">Row 2</td>
      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <p value="5.39" id="basePrice">5,39 €</p>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <form id="Menge">
          <input type="number" min="0" id="quantity" value="0" step="1.0">
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <form id="sum">
          <p><output id="field_sum" for="quantity">0</output> €</p>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the JavaScript code I have created so far

```
var table = document.getElementById("table_gebäck");

for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  let row = table.rows[i]
  (function () {
    const basePrice = document.getElementsByClassName("basePrice");
    const quantityInput = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity");
    const resOutput = document.getElementsByClassName("field_sum");
    quantityInput.addEventListener("change", function () {
      let currentQuantity = parseFloat(quantityInput.value);
      let currentBasePrice = parseFloat(basePrice.getAttribute("value"));
      resOutput.textContent = currentQuantity * currentBasePrice;
    });
  }());
}
```

**EDIT**

This also helped me

[Calculating total price by iterating in the table using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27695246/calculating-total-price-by-iterating-in-the-table-using-javascript)

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: ok so i would have to call it id= baseprice1, id= baseprice 2 and so on ?

Comment: Not only that ID was duplicated, others like `Menge`, `quantities` and `sum` as well. And instead of "numbering" all of those now, you should probably look into other ways to select elements - f.e. based on a class, and/or the relation to other elements in the DOM.

Comment: `<p value="1.39"` - paragraphs don't have a value attribute; you should use a _custom data attribute_ instead if you need to put additional information like this onto a more or less generic element.

Comment: But they have also the same class
I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: Methods like `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelector` can be called not just on document, but on specific elements as well - in which case, they will only select descendant elements.

Comment: I did edit the code 
unfortunatly it als works only for the first row and not for the following

Comment: @Setzi138 you change your code to use `getElementsByClassName`, but the html code still uses IDs, and `getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements. And the shown code does not run because of a syntax errors.

Comment: What you currently have, should not work at all. You can not access the element's values _directly_ via `getElementsByClassName`, you need to loop over what that returned, or access a _specific_ element, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Comment: And you are still calling it on `document`, which means it would select _all_ elements with the class.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but using floating-point numbers to sum up prices is a bad idea. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I'm really not sure what I have to change now to make it work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Summing a table column with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833230/summing-a-table-column-with-javascript)

Comment: [Searching for this wasn't terribly difficult](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+sum+cells+in+a+table); I used no special jargon except for the site-specific search and maybe putting the name of the language first.

Comment: Thanks for trying but the question was not to sum values up
the code works for the first row i want to know how i can make it work for the other rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the markup cleanup/sanitize task(s) one could implement kind of a *micro-component* approach.

A viable solution which also is agnostic to (decoupled from) a certain DOM hierarchy can be based on [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) access together with [bound handler data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) ...

```js
function jsonParse(value) {
  let result = null;
  try {
    result = JSON.parse(value);
  } catch(exception) {}
  return result;
}
function sanitizeFloatValue(value) {
  value = parseFloat(value);
  return Number.isFinite(value) ? value : null;
}

function updateTotalValueFromBoundContextData(/* evt */) {
  const { source, target, baseValue, toFixed } = this;
  const totalValue = baseValue * (sanitizeFloatValue(source.value) || 0);

  target.value = (typeof toFixed === 'number')
    ? totalValue.toFixed(toFixed)
    : totalValue;
}
function initializeUpdateTotalValue(componentRoot) {
  const source = componentRoot
    .querySelector('[data-base-value]');
  const target = componentRoot
    .querySelector('[data-total-value]');

  const baseValue = sanitizeFloatValue(source.dataset.baseValue) || 0;

  const config = jsonParse(componentRoot.dataset.updateTotalValue) ?? {};
  const toFixed = sanitizeFloatValue(config.toFixed);

  const context = { source, target, baseValue, toFixed };

  source
    .addEventListener('input',
      updateTotalValueFromBoundContextData.bind(context)
    );

  // initial update call
  updateTotalValueFromBoundContextData.call(context);
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-update-total-value]')
    .forEach(initializeUpdateTotalValue);
}
main();
```

```css
body { zoom: .8; }
tr, td { margin: 0!important; padding: 0!important; height: unset!important; }
```

```html
<form name="product-orders">
  <!-- <script src="calculation.js"></script> //-->
  <table class="u-table-entity">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="20%">
      <col width="2.1%">
      <col width="22%">
      <col width="21.7%">
      <col width="34.2%">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody class="u-table-alt-grey-5 u-table-body">
      <tr style="height: 55px;">
        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-1"><b>Produkt</b><span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
        </td>
        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-3"><b>Einzelpreis</b></td>
        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-4"><b>Menge</b></td>
        <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-5"><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 55px;" data-update-total-value='{"toFixed": 2}'>
        <td class="u-table-cell">Kornspitz</td>
        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <p value="1.39">1,39 €</p>
        </td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <input type="number"
            min="0" value="0" step="1"
            name="quantity-Kornspitz"
            id="quantity-Kornspitz"
            data-base-value="1.39"
          />
        </td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <p>
            <output for="quantity-Kornspitz" data-total-value>0</output>
            €
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 55px;" data-update-total-value='{"toFixed": 2}'>
        <td class="u-table-cell">Row 2</td>
        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <p value="5.39">5,39 €</p>
        </td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <input type="number"
            min="0" value="0" step="1"
            name="quantity-Row_2"
            id="quantity-Row_2"
            data-base-value="5.39"
          />
        </td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <p>
            <output for="quantity-Row_2" data-total-value>0</output>
            €
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 55px;" data-update-total-value>
        <td class="u-table-cell">float number calculation</td>
        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <p value="1.39">1,39 €</p>
        </td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <input type="number"
            min="0" value="5" step="1"
            name="quantity-Row_3"
            id="quantity-Row_3"
            data-base-value="1.39"
          />
        </td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <p>
            <output for="quantity-Row_3" data-total-value>0</output>
            €
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 55px;" data-update-total-value='{"toFixed": 4}'>
        <td class="u-table-cell"><code>toFixed</code> set to 4</td>
        <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <p value="5.39">5,39 €</p>
        </td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <input type="number"
            min="0" value="3" step="1"
            name="quantity-Row_4"
            id="quantity-Row_4"
            data-base-value="5.39"
          />
        </td>
        <td class="u-table-cell">
          <p>
            <output for="quantity-Row_4" data-total-value>0</output>
            €
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

***Edit***

> *"Thank you very much for sharing this But i have no idea how to use it – Setzi138"*

Ok, let me try then ...

Firstly, the OP needs to write valid markup, thus there are never duplicate values for any element's `id` property.

Secondly, this task should be solved as generic as possible. One e.g. should not implement any code which is tightly coupled to both a specific DOM hierarchy (or markup) or a too specific task like calculating a total price.

Thus one has to find a solution which easily adapts to other environments with equal tasks like here which actually is ... ***"Updating and displaying a total value calculated from a base value and a currently changed multiplier whenever this multiplier value changes"***.

The above carefully worded requirement gives the direction or even points to a solution's corner stones.

A main initialization task firstly needs to identify each structure before it can be initialized.

A viable approach is to utilize [custom `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) instead of `class` (coupled to layout and styling) and `id` (too specific, disqualifies for generic solutions) attributes. In addition one can provide any string based data to a custom attribute which can be accessed via an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)'s [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

Even though the approach claims to be as markup agnostic as can be, there is one precondition to it. The structure of such a *"micro component"* needs to have a root element and two other elements which both need to be nested under/within the component root.
One element is the trigger or source of the quantity changes and the other serves as target for the updated total value.

Utilizing `[data-*]` attributes also has no disadvantage with accessing such elements within the DOM since a solutions makes use of modern element queries via [`<element >.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and  [`<element >.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

The only things left now are a proper naming and the implementation itself.

...

*+++ to be continued +++*

...

With more iterations over the first shown approach one finally could provide a **module based** implementation of a **highly generic**, **customizable** and **self-initializing** component which due to the customization ability also runs in DOM environments where one is not allowed of changing the markup on a large scale ...

```js
// utility functions
function parseJSON(value) {
  let result = null;
  try {
    result = JSON.parse(value);
  } catch(exception) {}
  return result;
}
function sanitizeFloatValue(value) {
  value = parseFloat(value);
  return Number.isFinite(value) ? value : null;
}

function getCustomKeyFromAttributeSelector(selector) {
  return (/\[\s*data-(?<customKey>[^\s\]]+)(?:\s|\])/)
    .exec(selector)
    ?.groups
    ?.customKey;
}
function getDatasetKeyFromCustomAttributeSelector(selector) {
  return getCustomKeyFromAttributeSelector(selector)
    ?.toLowerCase()
    ?.replace((/-(\p{Ll})/gu), (match, char) => char.toUpperCase());
}

// component specific module based code
const updateTotalValueModule = (function () {
  const DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    calculation: {
      baseValue: 0,
      toFixed: 2,
    },
    selectors: {
      source: '[data-base-value]',
      target: '[data-total-value]',
    },
    eventType: 'input',
  }
  const DEFAULT_SELCTOR_COMPONENT = '[data-update-total-value]';

  function updateTotalValueFromBoundContextData(/* evt */) {
    const { source, target, baseValue, toFixed } = this;
    const totalValue = baseValue * (sanitizeFloatValue(source.value) || 0);

    target.value = (typeof toFixed === 'number')
      ? totalValue.toFixed(toFixed)
      : totalValue;
  }
  let currentConfigKey;

  function initializeUpdateTotalValue(componentRoot) {
    const { // config values.
      selectors = DEFAULT_CONFIG.selectors,
      eventType = DEFAULT_CONFIG.eventType,
      calculation = DEFAULT_CONFIG.calculation
    } = (parseJSON(
      componentRoot.dataset[currentConfigKey]
    ) ?? DEFAULT_CONFIG);

    const source = componentRoot.querySelector(
      selectors.source || DEFAULT_CONFIG.selectors.source
    );
    const target = source && componentRoot.querySelector(
      selectors.target || DEFAULT_CONFIG.selectors.target
    );
    if (source && target) {

      const baseValue = (
        calculation.baseValue ||
        sanitizeFloatValue(source.dataset[
          getDatasetKeyFromCustomAttributeSelector(
            selectors.source || DEFAULT_CONFIG.selectors.source
          )
        ]) || 0
      );
      const toFixed = sanitizeFloatValue(
        calculation.toFixed || DEFAULT_CONFIG.calculation.toFixed
      );
      const context = { source, target, baseValue, toFixed };

      source.addEventListener(
        eventType,
        updateTotalValueFromBoundContextData.bind(context)
      );

      // initial update call
      updateTotalValueFromBoundContextData.call(context);
    }
  }
  function initialize(customAttributeSelector) {
    const selector = (typeof customAttributeSelector === 'string')
      && customAttributeSelector
      || DEFAULT_SELCTOR_COMPONENT;

    currentConfigKey = getDatasetKeyFromCustomAttributeSelector(selector);

    document
      .querySelectorAll(selector)
      .forEach(initializeUpdateTotalValue);
  }

  // (module) export(s)
  return {
    initialize
  };

}());

// running the component ...

// ... does target any default-config conform component.
updateTotalValueModule.initialize();

// ... does target any custom specific component.
updateTotalValueModule.initialize('[data-auto-total-price]');
```

```css
body { zoom: .8; }
tr, td { margin: 0!important; padding: 0!important; height: unset!important; }
```

```html
<!-- <script src="calculation.js"></script> //-->
<table class="u-table-entity" id="table_gebäck">
  <colgroup>
    <col width="20%">
    <col width="2.1%">
    <col width="22%">
    <col width="21.7%">
    <col width="34.2%">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody class="u-table-alt-grey-5 u-table-body">
    <tr style="height: 55px;">
      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-1"><b>Produkt</b><span style="font-weight: 700;"></span>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-3"><b>Einzelpreis</b></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-4"><b>Menge</b></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell u-table-cell-5"><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 55px;" data-update-total-value ='{"calculation":{"baseValue":1.39,"toFixed":2},"selectors":{"source":"form input[type=\"number\"]","target":"form output"},"eventType":"input"}'>
      <td class="u-table-cell">Kornspitz</td>
      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <p>1,39 €</p>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <form name="amount_Kornspitz">
          <input type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" id="amount_Kornspitz">
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <form name="price_total_Kornspitz">
          <p>
            <output for="amount_Kornspitz">0</output>
            €
          </p>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 55px;" data-auto-total-price='{"calculation":{"toFixed":4},"selectors":{"target":"form output"}}'>
      <td class="u-table-cell">Row 2</td>
      <td class="u-table-cell"></td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <p>5,39 €</p>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <form name="amount_Row_2">
          <input type="number" value="5" min="0" step="1" id="amount_Row_2" data-base-value="5.39">
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="u-table-cell">
        <form name="price_total_Row_2">
          <p>
            <output for="amount_Row_2">0</output>
            €
          </p>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```